# bundler のインストールが失敗する

Tags: bundler, rubygems

`gem install bundler`のコマンドを打つと、以下のエラーが出てインストールされません。

```
    ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

どうすれば解決するでしょうか？

Comment: gemのバージョン、OSの情報などあると他の方の役に立つかもしれません。

Answer (score 10):

DNS障害でrubygems.orgに通信できない状況が発生しています。
復旧次第、成功するようになります。

コンソールからドメイン情報の取得を行うと状況が確認出来ます。

`host rubygems.org`

Comment: そうだったんですね！ありがとうございます。

Comment: DDoSを受けていたと教えてもらいました。状況は http://dnsimplestatus.com/ で確認できます。

Comment: @YusukeKatsuki 問題が解決したら、回答の左にあるチェックマークをクリックして解決済みにするとよいです。他の人にも分かりやすいですし、回答者と自分にポイントが入ります。

Answer (score 4):

自分も同じ件で困ってました。
現在は解決されていますが、次似たようなことが発生した場合、下記サイトを見るとすぐに落ちているかどうか判断できるかと思います。

Status - RubyGems System Status https://status.rubygems.org/

Pingdom Public Reports Overview http://uptime.rubygems.org/

Answer (score 3):

今日はrubygems.orgが不安定なようので、そのせいではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

ソースの場所を-r(Remove)し、有効な場所を-a(add)する

```
gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/ -a http://production.cf.rubygems.org/
```

戻す

```
gem sources -r http://production.cf.rubygems.org/ -a http://rubygems.org/
```

でいつもとりあえず解決させてます。

Answer (score 0):

-pオプションで、proxyを設定してみてください。

https://maku77.github.io/ruby/gem/gem-with-proxy.html