# bundle install時にタイムアウトする場合の原因と対処方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby, rubygems

`bundle install`をしたところ`time out`エラーが出ました。
こういう時って`rubygems.org`が落ちてるのでしょうか?

ブラウザからアクセスするとつながるのですが、gemがどういうものなのかよくわかっていないので教えて下さい。

また、こういう時はどうしようもないのでしょうか。
すぐに作業に取り掛かりたいのですが・・・

Comment: `rubygems.org`が落ちている場合についてはこちらを参照ください。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/229/3313

しかし、どうも手元ではつながるような。。もし可能でしたら原因のgemをお教えいただくか、Gemfileをご提示くだされば、閲覧している方にも詳細な原因がわかるかもしれません。

Comment: つながらないときは、ブラウザから、 https://status.rubygems.org/ を参照すると本当におちているかわかります。何が原因かわからないので、詳しいログを貼付けてくれると、助言する人が助かるかもしれない。

Answer (score 4):

現在つながらない問題は、twitterではsource 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org' に切り替えたら上手くいったという意見が見られますね。

すぐに作業に取り掛かりたいという事ですので、ミラーに切り替えて上手くいくのであれば今日は切り替えて作業されるといいでしょう。
切替はGemfileの先頭行を書き換えることで実現でき、Gemfileはrailsアプリを作成したディレクトリにあります。

```
rails new abc
```

と、した場合なら abcディレクトリにGemfileはあります。

今は先頭が

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

となっていると思いますが

```
source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'
# source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

このようにして保存してbundleコマンドを実行してみてください。

あくまで代理サイトなので、明日などひと段落したら元に戻しましょう。

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 2):

一時的にsourceを
https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org
に変更するとつながるかもしれません。

cf. [tokyo-m.rubygems.org が落ちていて rubygems がインストールできない。 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/Dominion525/items/f4614f34eb2d868bdeeb)

Answer (score 1):

よしじゃあ、あてずっぽうで。

つながらないときは、ブラウザから、  https://status.rubygems.org/ を参照してください。チェックが緑色なら、自分の ruby 環境周りを見ることになります。

つながらない理由はいろいろありますが、一つの考えられる原因として rubygem のバージョンが古いのかもしれません。(< 2.3)

```
gem update --system
```

をして、 gem を更新してから、もう一度お試しください。

参考: [Gems not installing due to timeout](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/17672-gems-not-installing-due-to-timeout)