# gem update --systemがタイムアウトします。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

環境：mac上のVirtualBoxでCentOS7.5(1804)
$ gem update --system を実行すると
ERROR: While executing gem...(Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
time out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs4.8.gz)
というメッセージが表示されます。

rubyのバージョンは、2.5.1(2.3.0でも試しました)
ちなみにapi.rubygems.orgへpingは通ります。

以上、よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: プロキシはお使いでしょうか？

Comment: 過去 rubygems.org が落ちたときの類似質問です: [「bundle install時にタイムアウトする場合の原因と対処方法を教えてください」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2750/19110) -- スタック・オーバーフロー

Comment: 環境が Ubuntu で異なりますが、IPv6 が使えなくなっていた、という場合を報告してらっしゃるブログがありました: [「Ubuntuでgem installできなくなった」](http://blog.t-skgm.com/post/172444882914/ubuntu%E3%81%A7gem-install%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F) -- I Know There's an Answer

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
教えていただいた「IPv6を無効」にすることで、
無事、インストールすることができました。

【方法】
①sysctl.conf を開く
$ sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf

②以下を追記
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

③sysctl.conf を保存して閉じる

④設定を反映
$ sudo -p

⑤IPv6 が存在しないことを確認
$ ip a

⑥gem update --system
アップデートできました。

Comment: `gem update -V` で通信情報の詳細が見れるようなので、補足情報としてコメントしておきます。IPv6 を無効化するのは望ましくないような気がするので、他の方法を見つけるヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

教えていただいた「IPv6を無効」にすることで、 無事、インストールすることができました。

【方法】
①sysctl.conf を開く
$ sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf

②以下を追記
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

③sysctl.conf を保存して閉じる

④設定を反映
$ sudo -p

⑤IPv6 が存在しないことを確認
$ ip a

⑥gem update --system

以上でアップデートできました。